# Optimize query of questions ordered by difficulty

Tags: mysql, view, query-optimization

I'm creating a View that contains questions that have to be ordered by difficulty.

My idea is:

- First put the new questions (less than 10 responses)
- Second put the questions that don't have any wrong response
- Finally the other questions ordered by difficulty

The way to calculate the difficulty is (answerCorrect / answerIncorrect)

The problem is that I think that a lot of queries over this view will be done and I suspect this query is quite slow, and I don't know if there is a way to do faster.

```
alter view questionLevel as select *, 0 as ordenacio from question where statsAnswerCorrect + statsAnswerIncorrect < 10
union
select *, 1 as ordenacio from question where 
statsAnswerCorrect + statsAnswerIncorrect >= 10
and statsAnswerIncorrect = 0
union
select *, 2 as ordenacio
from question where questionId IN (
select questionId from question where statsAnswerCorrect + statsAnswerIncorrect >= 10 
and  statsAnswerIncorrect > 0 )
order by ordenacio asc, ( statsAnswerCorrect / statsAnswerIncorrect) desc
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite your third part of union for ordenacio=2 as a simple query:

```
SELECT *, 2 AS ordenacio FROM question 
WHERE statsAnswerCorrect + statsAnswerIncorrect >= 10 
AND  statsAnswerIncorrect > 0
```

Also keep in mind that while ordering by division your divisor can be equal 0, which means mysql will assign it  NULL value and put rows with it at the end if you ORDER BY ... DESC, which is probably not what you want. Use `ORDER BY ( a/(b+1) ) DESC` or `ORDER BY ( a/(a+b) ) DESC` instead.

If you want to use this view a lot it might be better to denormalize your db a bit more and add columns keeping question type and correct percentage, updated on insert. It really depends on how big your tables are supposed to be and how many insert operations you expect.